# How to know status of file() requests after excution

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, file

I have this api

```
public function airtime()
  {
      $send = 
      file("https://www.example.com/APIQueryV1.aspUserID=CK123&
      APIKey=456&OrderID=789.............."); 

      if($send)
      {
          return $status->ORDER_COMPLETED;
      }

return $status->ORDER_COMPLETED;

}else return $status->ORDER_CANCELLED;
```

I also code like this

```
<?php
     if(isset(POST["aitime"]))  {

     $send file("https://www.example.com/APIQueryV1.aspUserID=CK123&
     APIKey=456&OrderID=789............."); 

     if($send)
     {
         return $status->ORDER_COMPLETED;
     }

     echo "SENT";

     }else  echo "NOT SENT";


?>
```

and this is the expected returning json

```
{"date":"17th-Mar- 2019","orderid":"798","statuscode":"200","status":"ORDER_COMPLETED","remark":"Success","mobilenetwork":"MTN","mobilenumber":"081xxxxxxxxxxx"

,"ordertype":"100 Credit","amountcharged":"95","walletbalance":"863210.1"}
```

I want to know echo sent if the status returns ORDER_COMPLETED or something else if the status returns something else but am not getting it correct, please need help.

Comment: `file()` is not the right function to use (it will break on pretty printed json), curl or file_get_contents

Comment: It works..Thanks

now I want to get the value of "status"

I have this

 `if($send)
     {
        Print_r($send);
     }
     
     }
     
echo $status;`

but didn't work


I have this json as output

`{"status":"INVALID_CREDENTIALS"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function airtime()
{
    $send = 
    file("https://www.example.com/APIQueryV1.aspUserID=CK123&
    APIKey=456&OrderID=789.............."); 

    if($send) {
        return $status->ORDER_COMPLETED; //return back from this function
    }

    //The code will only reach here if not completed
    return $status->ORDER_CANCELLED;

}


$result = airtime();

//Prints out value of `$status->ORDER_COMPLETED` or `$status- 
//>ORDER_CANCELLED`
echo $result;
```

---

The code wont work as it is because `$status` is not defined anywhere but above is the way to think to return based on true or false (`$send`)